# Python/regex: Elegant way to check if a string contains ONLY numbers and periods

Tags: python, regex, python-2.4

For example, '5243412..32.432242' would yield true, while '2132100345abcdefgh--#$#' would be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex

```
^[0-9\.]*$
```

Matches a line only consisting of digits and periods.

Answer (score 0):

A shortcut is to use '\d' which checks for digits.